# Dificuldade com instalação do YUI compressor do W3 Total Cache

Tags: wordpress, cache

Instalei recentemente o plugin *W3 Total Cache*, porém estou com dificuldade para instalar o Java. Veja a *screenshot*:

[image: SS]

Estive lendo em fóruns estrangeiros que é preciso a instalação do arquivo *YUI compressor* no servidor, porém estou com problema para descobrir qual pasta pôr, para que ele não de erro.

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes sobre que servidor está utilizando? me parece um detalhe pertinente a essa pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Caso seja um servidor ubuntu você poderia usar o proprio apt-get para faer a instalação

[Ubuntu](http://globerunner.com/install-yui-compressor-on-ubuntu-12-04-server-too-precise-pandolin/):

```
  sudo apt-get install yui-compressor
```

Em outra [referencia que encontrei](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272694/how-to-install-yui-compressor-in-centos), o arquivo jar foi copiado para a pasta `/usr/share/yui-compressor`

```
  wget http://yui.zenfs.com/releases/yuicompressor/yuicompressor-2.4.6.zip

  unzip yuicompressor-2.4.6.zip

  mv yuicompressor-2.4.6/build/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar /usr/share/yui-compressor/yui-compressor.jar
```

Depois foi criado o arquivo `yui-compressor` em `/usr/bin/`, criando uma variável de ambiente para executar o seu arquivo .jar

```
#!/bin/sh
YUI_JAR=/usr/share/yui-compressor/yui-compressor.jar
java -jar $YUI_JAR "$*"
```

Há também varias avisos para verificar a sua versão do java instalada.

Comment: Olá caro Guilherme,irei fazer os devidos testes e retorno oque consegui..

Obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Caro Guilherme,estou a usar o YUicompressor no plugin w3 total cache e pelo pequeno conhecimento sobre a plataforma,acredito não ter como usa-ló em chmod,estive lendo em fóruns par aver se era possível,não achei nada então se tiver como me dar um auxilio de como usar chmod para instalar o YuiCompressor no w3 agradeço,caso não saiba agradeço seu Tempo e consideração..

Sua resposta já valeu o Dia :) 

Valeu caro amigo...

Comment: Não consegui entender esse ultimo comentário...
chmod que eu conheço é um comando para definir as permissões de uma determinada pasta no ambiente linux/unix `sudo chmod -R 775 minha_pasta/`  te daria total permissão de escrita, por exemplo...